# How to print pop-up comment from Python to Excel?

Tags: python, excel, tooltip, mouseover

Is there anyway to print a comment from Python to Excel that will only be visible once you hover over the cell?

If so, can someone please help me find the right code. Thank you so much for any help that you may offer. I really appreciate it.

I found this online but I am not sure if it's right. I am new to coding and not sure how to implement this correctly.

```
# Set up some formatting.
worksheet1.set_column('C:C', 25)
worksheet1.set_row(2, 50)
worksheet1.set_row(5, 50)

# Simple ASCII string.
cell_text = 'Hold the mouse over this cell to see the comment.'

comment = 'This is a comment.'

worksheet1.write('C3', cell_text, text_wrap)
worksheet1.write_comment('C3', comment)
```

Comment: This might help https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_comments1.html

Comment: Awesome... Thanks you =)